# How to use Environments feature with pipeline release stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have defined a release pipeline using the classic view, now I'm wondering if it's possible to connect an Azure pipeline Environment with and existing stage in the release pipeline. If it's possible how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you refer to the new Environment in the preview, the features there include:

- Traceability of commits and work items
- Deployment history down to the individual resource
- Deeper diagnostics, and (soon) approvals and checks  etc

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops)，it seems that the environment feature can only be used in yaml . The sample given are all in yaml. It should be currently not supported in the classic view.

You can also refer to the **Building your first multi-stage pipeline with environments** part of this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/) .